# Cloud9: nodejs server image not getting rendered (HTML)

Tags: html, image, node.js, cloud9-ide

I have following setup in cloud9 IDE.

Project root folder

1. Hello.html - contains simple html tags (+image tag) *Preview displays the image*
2. HelloHtml.js - node js file that reads html file and writes to the client (response). .
3. Penguins.jpg - image file in the same folder.

When I run the service and hit the URL in browser, HTML gets rendered with "Hello World!" being displayed as . But the image is not getting rendered. What should be the src="" attribute in the img tag.

What should be the path for the image file? Thank you.

**HelloHtml.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./Hello.html', function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            response.end(data);
        });
}).listen(process.env.PORT); 
console.log('Hello World HTML Service has started.');
```

**Hello.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Node JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello world!</h2>
        <img src="Penguins.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling static files serving anywhere in your code, you are just serving the file 'hello.html' no matter what:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./Hello.html', function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            response.end(data);
        });
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Either make a routing scheme, based on the request url or use some static file server from here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-web-frameworks-static

I suggest you take a look at Express, it has that and route handling also: expressjs.com